# How do I pass POST information to the next rendered page using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, post

How do I pass POST information onto the next rendered page using Nodejs?

I'm authenticating a user login and if they input the right credentials, I want to pass the user's email onto the next rendered page (the user's dashboard) as a greeting.

Here's what I have so far - this successfully authenticates the user and loads their dashboard.

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response)
{    
var email = request.body.email;
var password = request.body.password; 

console.log("post received: %s %s", email, password);

var query = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = \'' + email + '\'' + 'AND      password = \'' + password + '\'';

pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
  client.query(query, function(err, result) {
  done();

  var numRows = result.rows.length;
  console.log("Row count: %d",result.rows.length)
  if (err)
  { console.error(err); response.send("Error: Could not execute query" + err); }
  else { 
    if (numRows == 0)
    {
      response.render('pages/loginerrorindex');
    }
    else {
    response.render('pages/dashboard', {results: result.rows} );
    }
  }
});
}); 
});
```

Comment: use session of some sort, or redirect with email?

Comment: Store user information in the session after successful login attempt. And write a new API to return session information. Use the output of this API to show the details on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the email to your view {results: result.rows, email: email}

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless. When you are authenticating users in web you must save their state in session or any storage available for both server and client to determine that next requests come from same user.

Server should generate secure session ID and create cookie.

Client send cookies on each request. Whenever user is authenticated your back-end application will receive your auth session cookie and you can get user ID for example from it.

Make an SQL query to get auth user data by his ID and display what you need. In any app or framework there us usually some kind of Auth object where you can get authenticated user via Auth.user() and you can check if user is authenticated:

```
if (Auth.check()) {
    // user = Auth.user() and display user menu, photo, e-mail
} else {
    // display Hello guest
}
```

Here is a simple auth example using popular NodeJS framework - Express.js
http://www.codexpedia.com/node-js/a-very-basic-session-auth-in-node-js-with-express-js/

**Now about sending POST data from one page to another page:**

Principle is same as with authentication described above. However, if you only need to display the information there are many ways doing it.

Classic approach in web development is again using session/cookies. Create a flash cookie and delete in in next request. Example, you want to display a successfull green message on next page when user logged in. On successfull login server creates flash cookie. On next request you are checking if flash cookie exists and if so - get content from it and render message, for example:

```
if (Flash.has('auth_message')) {
    // render message here <div>{{ Flash.get('auth_message') }}</div>
}
```

Another option is to do same flash logic only client-side using localStorage/sessionStorage.

In case if you have form with many steps it is not recommended to save each previous step data. It's complicated from code point of view and from UX because user should wait till next step will fully reloads. Multiple step forms should be implemented as small single page apps. Each next step should be hidden or loaded via ajax.